# Isogrammatic sentences?

Tags: single-word-requests

A [*pangram*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) is a sentence that uses each letter of the alphabet *at least* once.

- Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.
- How vexingly quick daft zebras jump.

A [*perfect* pangram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams#Perfect_pangrams_in_English_.2826_letters.29) uses each letter of the alphabet *exactly* once.

- TV quiz jock, Mr. PhD, bags few lynx.
- [Hjelmqvist-Gryb-Zock-Pfund-Wax](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol20/iss2/16/)

An [*isogram*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/isogram) (or [*heterogram*](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol31/iss3/5/)) is a *single word* that uses each letter *at most* once.

- uncopyrightable
- subdermatoglyphic

But what word/phrase describes a *sentence* that uses each letter *at most* once?

- Bide my frog’s quack.
- *Jaws* flunked copyright.
- Put back my English word!

Surprisingly, I can’t find any reference to sentences of this type either in a quick scan of [*Word Ways*](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/) or in Ross Eckler’s *Making the Alphabet Dance*.

Comment: I can't think of a word for that. (Or, put another way: BUD, MY LEXICON HAS 0.)

Comment: @J.R. I was also unsuccessful, but consider that "a **pangrammatic lipogram** or **lipogrammatic pangram** is a text that uses every letter of the alphabet except one". I'd suggest a **monogrammatic pangram** ("one letter pangram").

Comment: Polylipoheterogram?

Comment: @Zairja: It can't really be a pangram unless it uses every letter of the alphabet. He's asking instead for the name of a sentence with no duplicate letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by Wikipedia, the OP's definitions are a little too strict.

[Heterogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogram):

> A heterogram (from hetero-, meaning "different", + -gram, meaning "written") is a **word, phrase, or sentence** in which no letter of the alphabet occurs **more than once**.

[Isogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram):

> An isogram (also known as a "nonpattern word") is a logological term for a **word or phrase** without a repeating letter. It is also used by *some* to mean a **word or phrase** in which each letter appears the **same number of times, not necessarily just once**.

Ergo, it appears that the answer to the question is either *heterogram* or *isogram* depending on how pedantic one wants to be.

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither *hetero* nor *iso* can be appropriate for OP's case in a unique way.

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure I follow. Are they inappropriate because they are not unique? Or are they inappropriate because of their meaning?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that I have an answer for you other than that this may be a situation in which a word needs to be invented. Here is my stab:

- *Gram* is a suffix that refers to something being drawn or written.
- *Pan* is a prefix meaning all.
- *Iso* is a prefix meaning equal.

Thus, a sentence which uses each letter within it only once would then follow to also be described as an isogram. However, since defining both phenomena using the same word may be confusing, perhaps a phrase such as "complex isogram" is in order. Better yet, perhaps it could be considered a unigram.